# How many possible arrangements are there of the letters in the string AABBCC?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a group of $6$ elements with three different double elements such as AABBCC. I want to create number of possible arrangements that I can get with these 6 elements. Each arrangement should include exactly same elements as double. For example AAABCB is NOT acceptable! Also AABBCC and AACCBB are not same! How many arrangements would I get? Some elements would be ABBCCA, ABCBCA, CBACBA, etc.

Comment: What have you learnt in permutations ? Have you tried anything for this problem ? You are supposed to show what efforts you have made, and where you are facing problems.

Comment: Have you tried solving the equivalent problem for the string $AABB$?

Comment: With respect to N.F.Taussig's suggestion, after you manually count them, ask yourself what the relationship is between what you manually counted, and $(4!)$, which would be the enumeration if the letters were $ABCD$.  Think about the effects of *over-counting*.